# Difference between i++ and i+1 in array count

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

Consider:

```
int[] aryNums=new int[5];

for (int i=0; i<=5; i++)
{
    aryNums[i] = i++;
    System.out.println(aryNums[i]);
}
```

Why doesn't this give me the values in the array as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?
Instead, it gives an exception like 0,0 and error.

And also if I change

```
aryNums[i] = i++;  \to

aryNums[i] = i+1;
```

I get the value {1,2,3,4,5} in the array. What is the diff between i++ and i+1 here?

Answer (score 7):

`++` is an operator that changes the value of 'i' by 1. It's a shorthand notation of `i = i + 1`.

`i + 1` is an addition statement that returns what it normally would, but it doesn't change the value of i because i is not reassigned.

The reason you're getting errors is because `i++` uses `i` before incrementing it, whereas if you wanted to use it after incrementing, you'd need to use `++i` (increment, then use). Since `i++` is also incrementing your counter, some values will be skipped.

Comment: The third paragraph is a very important supplement to the first, as it explains the difference between pre- and post- increment operators.

Answer (score 3):

`a = i++;` equals to `a = i; i = i + 1;`

```
int[] aryNums=new int[5]; //array index starts from 0, so last index is "4"

for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, "5" -> out of bounds
{
    aryNums[i]=i++; //i++ -> first put the i to arrNums[i], "then" increase i
    System.out.println(aryNums[i]);
}
```

Solutions:

- Remove `=` from `i <= 5`
- Change `aryNums[i]=i++` to `aryNums[i] = i + 1`

Answer (score 2):

In the first one you are incrementing `i` inside the loop as well as part of the loop update.  In the second, you are simply creating a new integer when you call `i+1` without affecting the value stored at `i`.

The expression `i++` updates the value stored at `i`, whereas the expression `i+1` returns a new value without affecting the value stored at `i`.